# Key repeat in macOS very slow

Tags: macos

Here is a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/guKo5XtX8ww) to show what the issue is. All key events in the view are always pressed (<kbd>s</kbd> letter, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>delete</kbd>). The key repeat rate is very slow.

I'm sure this is not a hardware issue as I've been living with it for... Three (!!!) MacBook Pros. At first I thought it was and wanted to wait until the next MacBook Pro but now with the 16" MacBook Pro I'm still stuck with it. It's something with my OS that I can't afford to factory reset. It also doesn't occur when I gave my old MBP for my wife.

I've tried everything I could (it's been 4 years...), even with running the commands as in this post on [How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/267463/how-to-enable-key-repeating-in-%20macos/).

It's very frustrating at first but I'm kind of used to it… By not living with holding a key pressed but repeating it manually…

But now I really need help to fix this once and for all.

Comment: Test in another account. Test in Safe Mode. Make sure the control panel is set to full speed in both cases. Report back. Also see what the following commands return - `defaults read -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` and `defaults read NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat`

Comment: @Tetsujin tested with another account and it works fine. the value are: 0 and 2.

Comment: Try changing values on the sliders, see if the defaults echoes those values. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261163/default-value-for-nsglobaldomain-initialkeyrepeat where someone else had some kind of disconnect between the values. I'm not sure it was ever really resolved, but it might give a hint.

Comment: I've tried that, the values does echo when changing the sliders. In fact, I've tried that a dozen of times but it never help resolved the issue.

Comment: So long as the KeyRepeat never shows zero, that should be all it takes. Test on another user account or in safe boot & see if it persists. That might narrow it down to something 3rd party you have installed.

Comment: as I've mentioned on my first comment another account works just fine. I'm stuck here not knowing what to do next.

Comment: Short of wiping & restoring from Time Machine, I really don't know what else to suggest, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this! After 5 years LOL!!!

On macOS Big Sur (11.1), on startup there’s a notification at the middle of the screen that says “Slow Keys.” With this I was able to search the settings and found it under “Accessibility” settings in “System Preferences.”

[image: Slow keys]

Comment: Wow! Congrats on finally figuring this small nightmare out!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks (for the edits too). It is a nightmare indeed, I'd been so frustrated.